# Unexpected map reduce result with MongoDB 3.0

Tags: java, mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-java

I am trying to implement a map reduce for my website (using MongoDB 3.0, Java 7).

To get me started, I just want to test the functionality but my collection is not affected by its output:

```
    String map = "function(){"
            + "emit(\"testValue\", [5, 5, 10]);"
        + "}" ;

    String reduce = "function(key, values){"
            + "return Array.sum(values);"
        + "}";

    // INPUT COLLECTION
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = 
    MongoDBManager.getMongoCollection("colTest");

    // OUTPUT COLLECTION
    MongoCollection<Document> index = 
    MongoDBManager.getMongoCollection("index");

    // MAP REDUCE
    collection.mapReduce(map, reduce)
        .action(MapReduceAction.REPLACE)
        .collectionName("index");


    // SEE CONTENT OF INDEX
    FindIterable<Document> result = index.find();

    MongoCursor<Document> cursor = result.iterator();

    while(cursor.hasNext()){
        Document current = cursor.next();
        System.out.println(current.toString());
    }
    cursor.close();
```

Here is the output of the println:

```
Document{{_id=58f4098537a734176b1c140f, testID=0}}
```

colTest is not empty. Here is a sample:

```
{"messages": [
    {
        "date": 1492308383230,
        "likesNumber": 1,
        "_id": {"$oid": "58f2d19f37a734176941a0ef"},
        "likers": ["allen"],
        "content": "a",
        "username": "paul"
    },
    {
        "date": 1492308345420,
        "likesNumber": 0,
        "_id": {"$oid": "58f2d17937a734172897ea8b"},
        "content": "ab",
        "username": "allen"
    },
    {
        "date": 1492308287884,
        "likesNumber": 0,
        "_id": {"$oid": "58f2d13f37a73416ef3d214e"},
        "content": "abc",
        "username": "john"
    }
]}
```

I would like the following output...

```
{"testValue" : 20}
```

... as many times as there are documents (3 in my sample) in colTest.

Why does my collection remain unchanged? Is there something wrong in the code or should I expect this result?

Comment: Can you add a sample document from your `colTest` collection ? Why are you emitting hard coded values ? What field do you want the sum for ?

Comment: @Veeram Thanks for your hints! My documents were actually nested in an upper document. I edited my original post with a sample. Those hard coded values are simply there for testing purposes.

Comment: Np. Thank you for adding the sample doc. Can you tell what you are trying to achieve  ? What is the expected output ?

Comment: @Veeram I edited my post with the kind of results I would like to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below MapReduce query.

```
String map = "function() {\n" +
            "                   var array = [5, 5, 10];\n" +
            "                   for (var idx = 0; idx < array.length; idx++) {\n" +
            "                       var key = 'testValue';\n" +
            "                       var value = array[idx];\n" +
            "                       emit(key, value);\n" +
            "                   }\n" +
            "             };";

String reduce = "function(key, values) {return Array.sum(values);};";

// MAP REDUCE
collection.mapReduce(map, reduce).action(MapReduceAction.REPLACE).collectionName("index").first();
```

The `first` signals the driver to run the query.

This will output something like

```
Document{{_id=testValue, value=20.0}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! My main problem is to fetch the inner documents. With the following methods (and using your M/R) I got the expected results: `DBCollection collection = MongoDBManager.getDBCollection("messages");
 MapReduceCommand cmd = new MapReduceCommand(collection, map, reduce, null, MapReduceCommand.OutputType.INLINE, null);
 MapReduceOutput out = collection.mapReduce(cmd);`. It would force me to change the structure of my code though. I tried adding `.filter(new BasicDBObject("_id", new BasicDBObject("$exists", true)))` to the M/R call but couldn't get the expected results.

Comment: Np. You just have to iterate over inner documents and emit multiple values for same document. Example here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/map-reduce-examples/#calculate-order-and-total-quantity-with-average-quantity-per-item

Comment: If I understand correctly, I should iterate through my documents by adding a loop in the map function? I might be misunderstanding the principle behind map reduce, but isn't it ineffective to do such an operation in the map itself? Isn't it actually supposed to split the documents and apply the map function for each? Should I not be doing a find() (with .filter()?) on the set before map/reducing?

Comment: You are adding a loop for sub documents. It only splits the main documents. You should use filter if you want to limit the main documents. Btw you have efficient option than map reduce called aggregation. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Comment: Your suggestions were perfectly right and got it working using `MapReduceOutput out = collection.mapReduce(new MapReduceCommand(collection, map, reduce, null, MapReduceCommand.OutputType.INLINE, null));`! But as stated above, it would imply changing the structure of my code. I can't seem to make my original mapReduce `collection.mapReduce(map, reduce).action(MapReduceAction.REPLACE).collectionName("index");` working. Did I omit something? Anyway even if you can't find it out I will mark your post as the answer (you deserve it well ;) ).

Comment: You miss the `first()`. I would recommend using aggregation framework as map reduce is  old and uses java script engine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141847/discussion-between-kathandrax-and-veeram).